# How to group a pandas dataframe to list of Traces?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have sample data like below

```
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {"Col_1" : ["AB", "AC", "AD", "BD", "BC", "BW", "KA", "KB", "KK", "KL"],
             "Col_2" : [1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

```
  Col_1 Col_2
0   AB  1
1   AC  2
2   AD  1
3   BD  2
4   BC  2
5   BW  1
6   KA  1
7   KB  1
8   KK  2
9   KL  2
```

I'm trying to group the data with `Col_2` and return the grouped values as a list with two columns as `ID` and `Traces` as a `DataFrame`.

**Required output - Dataframe**

```
ID   Traces
1    ["AB", "AD", "BW", "KA", "KB"],
2    ["AC", "BD", "BC", "KK", "KL"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the column `Col_2` as `ID`, then group the dataframe by `ID`, finally apply aggregate using named aggregation passing i.e. passing it as keyword argument where keyword is the column name you want i.e. `Traces`, argument is the tuple with column name i.e. 'Col_2`to perform aggregation on, and the aggregation function i.e.`list`. (If needed, you can reset the index at last)

```py
>>> data.rename(columns={'Col_2': 'ID'}).groupby('ID').agg(Traces=('Col_1', list))

                  Traces
ID                      
1   [AB, AD, BW, KA, KB]
2   [AC, BD, BC, KK, KL]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
data.groupby('Col_2')['Col_1'].apply(list).reset_index().rename(columns={'Col_2': 'ID', 'Col_1': 'Traces'})
```

**Output**

```
ID                Traces
0   1  [AB, AD, BW, KA, KB]
1   2  [AC, BD, BC, KK, KL]
```